# Custom ImageView with custom styling (How-To, Name)

Tags: android

I'd like to know the name of such effect to the following screenshot. For example, the image is full loaded as a Rec, then it has an extra space with an angled white/dark space.

- I literally have no idea how to better explain this.
- I don't want a code sample, just hints so i can know how to do such custom styles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first and second screenshot: you can use **Relative Layout**

Firstly, insert the **imageView**, then insert the **white layout** with needed dimensions and margins, so it will overlap the **imageView**.